# task scheduled in laravel for sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

my project in laravel 5.5 and mysql have a start and end date for users to register in my web site
When the time ends on a date determined by the administrator, the following function must be executed in laravel:

```
public function select()
{

        seleccion::create([
            'emp_id' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
            'dst_id' => 'Success',               
        ]);   


}
```

I read the laravel documentation but I do not know what to use

- Task Scheduling
- commands
- event / listeners
- Scheduling Queued Jobs
- ???

those methods do not tell me how to execute a function once on a certain date.

Comment: Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling - In summary, you can make a function to do whatever you wish, send emails, do checks, updates, etc in a scheduled manner. Could be every minute, every day, every 60 days etc.

Comment: thanks but on my web server I do not have access to cron because my server is shared

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's a single date upon which this function needs to execute, I would simply schedule an Artisan `Command`

You'd first have to create a command, which you can do by running:

```
php artisan make:command ExpireRegistrations
```

Then you'd add your code to the `handle()` method of the `command`

Then you would schedule the command to be executed on the date you require, by adding it to `App/Console/Kernel.php`

See the laravel docs for the scheduling syntax: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Lastly, you'll want to ensure that the Laravel
Cron job is set to run on your server by adding this to your Cron Tab:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:
```

Comment: thanks unfortunately I do not have access to cron since my web server is shared, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @jhoss are you sure? Most shared hosts allow you to add cron job entries in CPanel, and interfaces like that

Comment: no, it does not have to because my web server is very limited
I think I'll have to get one better thanks